# How to create a pdf file and send email with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email-attachments

I have a controller and an Exporter class to create pdf of one class data in Spring boot. It works at localhost. And I can send emails with attachments which are in the resources/static/ directory from this link:
https://asbnotebook.com/2020/01/26/send-email-with-attachment-spring-boot/

I want to email the pdf file created at fly. I tried to combine them but it didnt work.

```
 public String sendMail(EmailRequestDto request, Map<String, String> model) {
 
        String response;
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
           
            Template template = configuration.getTemplate("email.ftl");
            String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, model);
 
            helper.setTo(request.getTo());
            helper.setFrom(request.getFrom());
            helper.setSubject(request.getSubject());
            helper.setText(html, true);
            
            List<PurchaseDetail> cities = (List<PurchaseDetail>)basketService.getPurchases();
                      
                      ByteArrayInputStream bis = InvoicePdfExporter.citiesReport(cities);
                      
                      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add("ContentDisposition",
                      "inline; filename=citiesreport.pdf");
                      InputStreamResource rs= (new InputStreamResource(bis)) ;
            
            //this gives error because rs is a inputStreamResource but not InputStream
helper.addAttachment("citiesreport.pdf",newByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(rs)));
 
            mailSender.send(message);
            response = "Email has been sent to :" + request.getTo();
        } catch (MessagingException | IOException | TemplateException e) {
            response = "Email send failure to :" + request.getTo();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

And my working controller class which creates pdf. InvoicePdfExporter class adds datatable to document and returns as return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdfreport", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces =    MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE) 
            public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> citiesReport() throws IOException
            {

            List<PurchaseDetail> purchases = (List<PurchaseDetail>)
            basketService.getPurchases();

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = InvoicePdfExporter.citiesReport(purchases);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add("Content-Disposition",
            "inline; filename=citiesreport.pdf");

            return
            ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(bis)) ; }
}
```

I really need help I really dont understand from IOStreams, I tried many things but none of them  solved my problem. Thanks!!

Edit:
I solved this problem by changing the return type of my InvoicePdfExporter to InputStreamSource and changed to this:

```
List<PurchaseDetail> cities = (List<PurchaseDetail>)basketService.getPurchases();
                      
      InputStreamSource bis =InvoicePdfExporter.citiesReport(cities);
                      
                      
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add("Content-Disposition",
                      "inline; filename=citiesreport.pdf");
                      
                      
                      
            helper.addAttachment("citiesreport.pdf",bis, "application/pdf" );
```